# related rates what units to use when rate given is in different units to final answer

Tags: calculus

The length of a particular rectangle is four times its width and this ratio is
maintained as the width is increased at 2 mm/sec. Find the rate of increase in the area of the rectangle when the width is 15 cm.

So I get the rate of increase of area to be 16w (w=width), keeping the rate of width increase in millimetres. I than convert 15cm also into millimetres to keep things consistent, but when I solve it:

16*150=2400mm/sec

I get the wrong answer (240mm/sec). If however, I do everything in cm, I get the correct answer and I can't figure out why. I think it has to do with the differentiation of the area with respect to width having associated units, but if that's the case, I'm really confused as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $l = 4w$, the area $A = lw$ can be expressed as a function of $w$.
$$A(w) = (4w)w = 4w^2$$
Differentiating with respect to time yields
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 8w \frac{dw}{dt}$$
If we work with $\text{cm}$, we obtain
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 8(15~\text{cm})\left(0.2~\frac{\text{cm}}{\text{s}}\right) = 24~\frac{\text{cm}^2}{\text{s}}$$
If we work with $\text{mm}$, we obtain
$$\frac{dA}{dt} = 8(150~\text{mm})\left(2~\frac{\text{mm}}{\text{s}}\right) = 2400~\frac{\text{mm}^2}{\text{s}}$$
Since there are $10~\text{mm}$ in $1~\text{cm}$, there are $(10~\text{mm})^2 = 100~\text{mm}^2$ in $1~\text{cm}^2$, so the answers are equivalent.